# how to send HTML email

Tags: html, jakarta-mail

I have to send HTML file via email but not as attachment.

```
Message simpleMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
try {
   fromAddress = new InternetAddress(from);
   toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);

} catch (AddressException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    simpleMessage.setFrom(fromAddress);
    simpleMessage.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, toAddress);

    simpleMessage.setSubject(subject);
    simpleMessage.setText(text);

    Transport.send(simpleMessage);
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It is sending email simply with text message.
I want to send HTML content which is stored in another file but not as attachment

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Don't upcast your [`MimeMessage`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html) to `Message`:

```
MimeMessage simpleMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
```

Then, when you want to set the message body, either call

```
simpleMessage.setText(text, "utf-8", "html");
```

or call

```
simpleMessage.setContent(text, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

If you'd rather use a charset other than `utf-8`, substitute it in the appropriate place.

JavaMail has an extra, useless layer of abstraction that often leaves you holding classes like `Multipart`, `Message`, and `Address`, which all have much less functionality than the real subclasses (`MimeMultipart`, `MimeMessage`, and `InternetAddress`) that are actually getting constructed...

Comment: I'm using the code in question with `simpleMessage.setContent(text, "text/html; charset=utf-8");` to set the content but when doing it, every where in content that I have a question mark `=` it is converted to `=3D` which prevents HTML properties to be set correctly, any idea why?

Comment: @mohamnag You'll probably notice that the resulting message has a header reading `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable`. (This is likely because you're including non-ASCII text in your HTML part and email doesn't like non-ASCII content.) The recipient of the message will need to transfer-decode the message content to convert those `=3D`s back to `=`s. Try using `MimeMessage.getInputStream` instead of `MimeMessage.getContentStream` on the recipient side.

Comment: @dkrap thanks for mentioning it, I was ignoring transfer encoding and resulted HTML was not showing up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my sendEmail java program. It's good to use setContent method of Message class object.

```
message.setSubject(message_sub);
message.setContent(message_text, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

sendEmail.java

```
package employee;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SendEmail {

    public static void sendEmail(String message_text, String send_to,String message_sub ) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        
        final String username = "hello@xyz.com";
        final String password = "password";

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "us2.smtp.mailhostbox.com"); //replace your host address.
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //TLS
        
        Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sender@xyz.com", "Name from which mail has to be sent"));
            message.setRecipients(
                    Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(send_to)
            );
            message.setSubject(message_sub);
            message.setContent(message_text, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            
          

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```