# Send meeting invite with HTML content using Java Mail API

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, content-type

I want to send a meeting invite with HTML content using `JavaMail` API.

The confusion for me is that for sending a mail as a meeting invite, I need to use `content-type` `text/calendar` & for sending a mail as an `HTML` the `content-type` to be used is `text/html`.

However, in my case, I need to use both calendar and html, but I don't know how.

Request you guyz to please help me here.

Thanks,
Ankan

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223079/how-to-send-html-email)

Comment: Examples can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121715/how-to-send-an-ical-meeting-request-using-java-mail-and-recieve-the-response "JavaMail iCal") and [here](http://valermicle.blogspot.de/2009/02/i-was-searching-for-documentations-on.html "JavaMail Outlook calender")

Answer (score 0):

"**X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html**: html code will come here"

this can be use to send HTMl content in calendar invite